# How to unit test this lambda code?

Tags: python, unit-testing, lambda

Say, I have something like the following Python code:

```
try:
    from fabulous.color import fg256
    format_info = lambda x: fg256(63, unicode(x, 'utf-8')).as_utf8
except ImportError:
    format_info = lambda x: '\033[1;30m' + x + '\033[0m'
```

*How can I unit test this?*

*Is it worth testing?*

There is a need to mock the import statement so that both branches are excised.  This is fairly trivial -- for example, mock `fg256` to have a side effect of `raise ImportError`.

Matching that the returned string has the right control characters is fine but feels brittle.

Comment: Why would even want to test that? In the first case it seems like the tests should be already performed *by the package writer*, and the latter case... its correctness can be formally proved in 2 lines.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Well, I am the package writer so really I should test this... It *might* indeed not warrant a test and that would make a fine answer. Question edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is it that you want to test? You seem to have two unrelated cases here;

- importing fails
- lambda returns correct info

It's not really your responsibility to check that not using your code fails; but if you want to test this nevertheless (perhaps because this is code somebody has posted on a popular forum) I would separate it into two distinct tests.

We don't know what your lambda is supposed to return, but by the looks of it, it should return a string similar to what you assign in the `except` branch?